# HTML form post method isn't functioning

Tags: php, html, forms, post, http-post

It's probably something incredibly simple, however I feel like my brain is fried from staring at a computer screen for so long, so any pointers would be appreciated...

I cannot seem to get `$_POST` to work on my form. When I switch the method to `GET` - it works fine, but I don't want to have to repeatedly pull form data from the URL as it's quite a lengthy form and would take extra steps etc.

My form data:

```
<form action="<?= site_url() ?>shop/mock/form/<?= esc($first['gtin']); ?>" name="myForm" method="post">

    <div class="p-3 p-lg-5 border">

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="brand_name" class="text-black">Brand Name </label>
                <input type="text" value="<?= esc($_POST['brand_name']); ?>" class="form-control" id="brand_name" name="brand_name">
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php if (isset($_POST['brand_name'])): ?>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="subbrand_name" class="text-black">Subbrand Name </label>
                <input type="email" value="<?= esc($_POST['subbrand_name']); ?>" class="form-control" id="subbrand_name" name="subbrand_name" placeholder="">
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
</form>
```

The only thing I can think of is that I'm sending the form back to the same address everytime, and trying to grab the `$_POST` data from the latest submission, and repopulate the input values so that the form builds with every submission and reveals the next input etc. `var_dump($_POST)` shows an empty array every time.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: After a redirect it isn't a POST request anymore. The POST data is lost.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to receive otp in the form then action empty, if you want to receive from other action, you must put the value into $_SESSION